# `Import-Module posh-git` no longer works in Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-code, posh-git

I've been using this very handy CLI in the Visual Studio Code terminal for years, but since about a week ago I haven't been able to see any of the output. I can see it in Windows Powershell.

`C:\Users\me\projects\project1 [Branch-Name +3 ~3 -1 !]>`

But in VSCode I just get

`C:\Users\me\projects\project1>`

Anyone know if there's any way to fix this, or somewhere I should raise an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if this is similar to [posh-git issue 931](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/931):

> The new feature that shows color coded dots in the margin for successful/failed command executions. [Read more here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/shell-integration#_command-decorations-and-the-overview-ruler). It prevents the prompt from being adapted by Posh-Git.
>
> So on loading of Posh-Git, the prompt stays the same. (posh-git does load, and stuff like branch name completion does work, it's just the adaptation of the prompt function that fails.)
>
> I realize this is not a problem of Posh-Git per se. I just wanted to make you aware of this.
>
> I found a work-around by setting `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled` to `false`, and restarting the terminal.

If not, check your [profile script](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#step-2-import-posh-git-from-your-powershell-profile), to make sure it is still there, accessible and readable.